# Accessing JSON data structure in callback function

Tags: json, callback, getjson

I have the following data structure returning from a Yahoo API:

```
cbfunc({
    "query": {
        "count": 1,
        "created": "2011-02-16T00:48:51Z",
        "lang": "en-US",
        "results": {
            "place": {
                "woeid": "2487956"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In my code, I'm trying to access it as follows:

```
$.getJSON(url,function(json)
{
    $.each(json.query.results.place, function(i, item)
    {
        alert(item.woeid);
    });
});
```

but it is not working. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was premature in asking this question. I did an ajax setup like so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({"error":function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {   
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }});
```

and everything was fixed. Well, at least I found out that there was a parse error and then reformatted the data!

Sorry for the post!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is JSONP and not JSON. you could've used an eval on the returned json, by writing a function called cbfunc.